# App crashes when generating bitmap

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-studio, bitmap

So I wrote this app that should take picture with intent then draw fullscreen bitmap, but when I take picture app says please wait and then crashes. Here is my code:

```
  ImageView iv;
  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO = 101;
  private String path;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File output = new File(dir,"pic.png");
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(output));
    path = output.getAbsolutePath();
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me and show where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is you forget to `setContentView(....);` in `onCreate(....)`

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

because of this your app getting crash at

```
 iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

because `iv==null`

Comment: It is set I just forgot to include it.